# Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator : The 'parameters.properties' segment in the url is invalid

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, powershell-az-module

There is an issue with Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator not working in Azure DevOps release pipeline due to the latest az version 11.3.1 pushed by Azure to all pipeline agents. This could be because it uses az.sql = 4.14.0.

github open issue : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/23509

Answer (score 1):

#### Workaround

As the issue is from Az.Sql 4.11.0, we can use the [Az 10.4.1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/10.4.1) which contains Az.Sql 4.10.0 before the bug issue is resolved.

In Azure PowerShell task, set the `preferredAzurePowerShellVersion` to 10.4.1.

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'wxcss'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      # You can write your azure powershell scripts inline here. 
      Write-Host "Hello World"
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '10.4.1'
```

Another workaround is to use the Azure CLI with [az sql server ad-admin create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server/ad-admin?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-server-ad-admin-create) command.